# Can I disconnect the upstream port of an ethernet switch to create a local network without Internet?

Tags: switch, tcp, ethernet

I have two computers connected to an ethernet switch. The switch is connected to my ISP router for internet access, through the switch upstream port (of course). What happens if I unplug the upstream port?

My goal is simple: I want to have a local LAN *without* Internet access, but I still want to be able for my two machines to talk to each other thorough TCP. Is it possible or once I disconnect the upstream port my network is dead? Does it depend on the switch?

I'm buying a cheap 1000 Mbps switch for $15 at Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should work as you expect as long as your IPs are set static and in the same network segment.

Comment: A 15$ "switch" that acts as a DHCP server and uses IP segmentation? I think you are confusing switch and router

Comment: You're right, IPs would have to be set static. I'm going to update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dynamic (automatic) IP addresses provided by DHCP from the ISP router and unplug the link between the switch and the router, then you'll lose the DHCP server. While this will not be a problem right away, once the "lease" period (usually several hours) runs out your clients will give up their current address and can't get a new one.

The machines without a DHCP address will likely fall back to a random "zeroconf" address from the 169.254.x.y range. This will in turn reenable them to talk to each other once they've all moved over.

Alternatively, you can either manually configure a static IP address from the same network on each machine, or you can unplug the WAN port from the ISP router, removing its Internet connection without removing the router and its DHCP server from your network altogether.